# When can I discard the Death Creeper Card?

Tags: fluxx

On the Death card it says you can remove it when it stands alone. So my question is, As soon as I draw it and it stands alone can I remove it right then, or do I have to wait till my next turn to discard it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer.

The card text says:

> If you have this at the start of your turn, discard something else you have in play (a Keeper or a Creeper). You may discard this anytime it stands alone.

This card has two effects:

- The first effect, discarding something in play, must take place at the start of your turn (as accurately explained in the other answer).
- The second effect, being able to discard Death itself, can be done at "any time".

I believe the second is the effect you are asking about. That means that **if, at any point during anyone's turn, that is the only card you have in play, you may discard it**. To answer your specific scenario. If you draw it (and automatically play it) and it is the only card in front of you, you can discard it immediately.

Comment: The rules state, "Players take turns going clockwise." And the **Optional Rules** is inside the box labeled "On **your** turn." (Although I agree with your interpretation that the second ability is separate from the "If you have this at the start of your turn," rule.) There is also the issue of drawing multiple creepers during a multiple card draw event. If the first draw is Death (and you have no other cards/keepers in play), can you immediately discard it since it is alone before drawing a second card that is a Creeper?

Comment: @user1873 I still disagree, though Fluxx doesn't really have (or want) a rigid rule structure to settle this kind of dispute. As far as I'm concerned, all rules are stated on the appropriate cards, and "anytime" suggests to me that it's not restricted to your turn but can happen at _any_ time. My interpretation would still be as in my answer because of this wording. I've looked and haven't found any clarification either way, so I think it ultimately comes down to interpretation.

Comment: @user1873 (And for while drawing Creepers, I'd allow the player to discard Death immediately - if it was the only one - before drawing to replace it. Again this could be open to interpretation.)

Comment: Agreed, it is open to some interpretation, but since the **Optional Actions** rule is in the **On Your Turn:** box, I would lean towards that interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Johno. Just picked up the game last week and some of the scenarios and rules are unclear. Thanks again!

Comment: @MattF Glad I could help and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

You can discard it at any point **during your turn**, if it is alone at the end of the draw

The rules text on the Death Creeper card says (emphasis mine):

> If you have this at the start of your turn, discard something else you have in play (a Keeper or a Creeper). **You may discard this anytime it stands alone.**

[The Rules](http://www.looneylabs.com/literature/fluxx-rules) state under the **On Your Turn:** box, "**Optional actions** allowed by New Rules, Keepkers, etc may be performed at any point during this sequence." The Death Creeper's last ability, may be performed at any point during **your turn**. (With a minor exception mentioned in the **Creeper Rules** when drawing multiple cards, "You might have to accept several Creepers **at once** as you draw cards, **until** you've drawn the required number of non-Creepers and added them to your hand.")

Also [from the FAQ](http://wunderland.com/LooneyLabs/Fluxx/FAQ.html), you cannot take any actions during other players turns, so **anytime** isn't as often as you think.

> Q: Do I get to play any cards or take any actions when it's not my turn?
>
> A: When it's someone else's turn, there's not much you get to do -- there are no cards you can play out of turn. But you will sometimes need to make minor decisions and perform card maintenance during other players' turns. For example, if someone plays a Hand Limit and you have more cards in your hand than are allowed, you'll need to decide what to keep and what to discard.

Comment: the second sentence of the card gives when; it's easier to see if the sentence is paraphrased: *Anytime this card stands alone, you may discard it.* The anytime is part of when...